# How do I auto run a cmd when vscode open devcontainer?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I write my notes by vscode's devcontainer, it's sphinx. So I want add [sphinx-autobuild](https://github.com/executablebooks/) to auto build my notes when any .rst file changed.

This cmd is `sphinx-autobuild /workspaces/notes /workspaces/notes/_build/html/`.

I append `CMD sphinx-autobuild /workspaces/notes /workspaces/notes/_build/html/` in Dockerfile, it does not work clearly.

How do I run this cmd automatly after devcontainer was opened?

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I find the answer.

According to [devcontainerjson-reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference), `postCreateCommand`, `postStartCommand` and `postAttachCommand` can be used to run a command when a container be created or be started or be attached.

So, to run `sphinx-autobuild` after vscode opened, just append

```
"postAttachCommand": "sphinx-autobuild /workspaces/notes/ /workspaces/notes/_build/html/",
```

to `devcontainer.json`.

`postAttachCommand` be a type of string or array.